# Do keys in separate loops still need to be unique among siblings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, key

I was wondering how does the `key` work in loops. Do they create a separate branch, or do they still need to be unique for the same parent? This is what I'm talking about:

```
// This is obviously an error:
<div>
    <div key="gimme-a-break" />
    <div key="gimme-a-break" />
</div>

// This is an error too:
<div>
    {<div key="gimme-a-break" />}
    {<div key="gimme-a-break" />}
</div>

// Still an error:
<div>
    {(() => <div key="gimme-a-break" />)()}
    {(() => <div key="gimme-a-break" />)()}
</div>

// But, surprisingly, this is fine:
<div>
    {["boo"].map(() => <div key="gimme-a-break" />)}
    {["boo"].map(() => <div key="gimme-a-break" />)}
</div>
```

Is it just that React's parser can't figure out that the keys are duplicated, or do they indeed got separate context in the last example?

The official documentation says:

> Keys used within arrays should be unique among their siblings. However, they don’t need to be globally unique. We can use the same keys when we produce two different arrays.

But this is not clear whether the separate loops creating siblings for the same parent need to have unique keys too or not.

Is there some source explaining how it works?

Comment: How its related to loops? The definition states: "**... used within arrays**", only your last example applies the definition. You can also try: `{[<div key="gimme-a-break" />, <div key="gimme-a-break" />]}` which is also by definition.

Comment: I think your main confusion is **what considered as a valid React node** (strings, boolean, objects created by React API [=React.createElement] etc.), which includes **array of React nodes**. 

The keys hint is referring to this type.

Comment: Have you tried the new docs explanation? https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/rendering-lists#rules-of-keys

Comment: @DennisVash oh, so an array serves as a separate node, correct?

Comment: @DennisVash cool, it explains it. I thought the rendered nodes are rendered in their parent context. Thanks a bunch, I'll approve your answer as soon as it's ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An **array type** is a valid React child (more correctly an array of React nodes);

The keys hint applies to React nodes of **array type**.

For validation, refer to next [babel JSX transform](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=3.6&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAwiAtgB3AUzLAvDAFAShiwD4YBvAKBhgCc0oBXGsPK6mAHmLffIG0OAEwCWANxgBrNAE8sAIgDmwxIjQBaAIZqARnQ0S5MAPTEANJxHipsxctWadeg8eIBdAL49OJtvgDcFO5-QA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.20.6&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D) and [React.createElement API](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) (third arg is `children` array):

```
const Component = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {[<div key="gimme-a-break" />, <div key="gimme-a-break" />]}
    </>
  );
};


// Transforms to
"use strict";

const Component = () => {
  return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(React.Fragment, null, [/*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("div", {
    key: "gimme-a-break"
  }), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("div", {
    key: "gimme-a-break"
  })]);
};

// Hint, you can check this transform, but might be more confusing
const Component2 = () => {
  return (
    [<div key="gimme-a-break" />, <div key="gimme-a-break" />]
  );
};
```